# Calculating distance between places and user location Android Studio

Tags: java, sorting, android-studio, location, comparison

how can I calculate distance between list of locations against users' location and then display the list in a location sorted order stating how many miles the location is from user. Something like below;

[image]

I am not sure how I can do this in Java/Android

I understand for this we need to use sorting algorithm, to sort the list in order of nearest distance and write a comparing algorithm that compares given postcodes. I am not sure how I can approach this in Java/Android. I spent time searching online but couldn't find / fit what I found which the goal I am trying to achieve. Any help or guidance would be really nice.

Also, I am not sure how to get miles between the two locations.